# remove session in javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, session

we all know that we can set and get `session` using javascript like below:

```
session.setItem("name", "value");
```

session.getItem("name");

I need to know how to destroy particular and all session variable in javascript.

I used [google](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=kUAuVb6AGLHv8wfjy4CgCQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=destroy%20session%20variable%20in%20javascript) but I'm unable to get exactly what I need. Please help me to find the solution. jQuery answers are also welcome (without plugin)

Thank you in advance

Comment: `removeItem(keyName)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem

Comment: Clear all sessions is for `sessionStorage.clear();`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I assume this is [session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) in html5, in which case you can use

```
sessionStorage.clear();
```

to remove all items in the session storage or

```
sessionStorage.removeItem('itemName');
```

to remove a specific item.

Answer (score 1):

> clear(void):void This public method remove everything from the
>   sessionStorage object.

https://code.google.com/p/sessionstorage/

I didn't test my self but I think it should work.